# I/CameraFramework: handleMessage: 16

Tags: android, распознавание-символов

пробую реализовать распознавание с помощью Mobile Vision Text API из вот [этого](https://devcolibri.com/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-android-mobile-vision-text-api-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82/) примера, но почему то на моем устройстве не работает, циклично получаю сообщение:

`I/CameraFramework: handleMessage: 16`

В других устройствах, точнее устройствах более новой версии Андроида все нормально работает.

P.S. у меня андроид версии 5.1

Comment: В версиях api 21, 22 происходили некоторые изменения в принципах работы с камерой, внимательно почитайте об этом переходном периоде. Скорее всего у вас проблема кроится именно втонкостях разности работы под разные версии API.

Comment: @Valeriy спасибо за отклик. Где можно почитать можете ссылку

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager здесь самое основной ресурс, справа стоит номер API с которой он используется. А я сейчас и не вспомню, читал про это на разных ресурсах воюя с flash.

Comment: @Valeriy, походу этот АПИ работает для не менее 26й версии... https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision#pre-requisites

Comment: @Valeriy, а что лучше использовать для распознавание tesseract или mobile vision

Comment: Никогда не стыкался с данной задачей, потому ничем вам не смогу помочь. Раз вы говорите что на более новых нормально работает, ограничьтесь минимально работоспособной версией и развивайте свой проект.